# What is the difference between getIntent/URI/Text in clipboard?

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I am trying to understand the simple difference between getIntent(), getURI() and getText() in android, but it is very confusing from layman perspective. Couldn't find a similar question in stackoverflow.

- A URI is already a text, then how is getURI() any different from getText(). In what scenarios does Clipboard saves a URI and text/plain mime-types ?
- Does clipboard saves Intent mime-types only when they are called from a program ? or can Intents be saved by copying a file/app in filesystem in the mobile (This might be a wierd question though because I was never able to copy a file/app shortcut in mobile)

In a nutshell, can someone explain the scenarios of when a Text/URL/Intent gets saved in clipboard ? Any help will be appreciated.